# Trouble with small game

Tags: javascript, html, function

Im trying to  make a small game and I am having trouble displaying a randomly selected question when a specific player is chosen. Sort of hard to explain but the code helps you to understand.

I'm having problems getting the question onto the screen, then also changing the question when another button is clicked.

```js
const Questions1 = [
    "Most likely to break a world record?", 
    "Most likely to become a CEO?", 
    "Most likely to never get married?",
    "Most likely to commit a crime?",
    "Most likely to become prime minister?",
    "Most likely to give their kid an unusual (terrible) name?",
    "Most likely to be late for everything?",
    "Most likely to get lost in their own hometown?",
    "Most likely to accidentally poison someone with terrible cooking?",
    "Most likely to lock themselves out of their own home?",
    "Most likely to cancel plans at the last moment?",
    "Most likely to be killed first if they were in a horror movie?",
    "Most likely to break their phone the first day they get it?",
    "Most likely to cry whilst watching a sad movie?"
]

const Questions2 = [
    "Who is most likely to actually be a spy?",
    "Who is most likely to finish a jug of ice cream in one sitting?",
    "Who is most likely to miss their flight because they packed at the last minute?",
    "Who is most likely to call in sick at work to go to the beach?",
]

var truth = Questions1[Math.floor(Math.random() * Questions1.length)]
var lie = Questions2[Math.floor(Math.random() * Questions2.length)]


const players = []

numberPlayers = prompt("How many players?")

for (i = 0; i < numberPlayers; i++) {
    const playerName = `Player ${i + 1}`;
    const playerInt = true;
    const question = "";
    players.push({ name: playerName, intention: playerInt, question: question});
}

players[Math.floor(Math.random() * players.length)].intention = false

for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    if (players[i].intention === true) {
        players[i].question = truth;
    } else {
        players[i].question = lie;
    }
}
console.log(players)


for (x = 0; x < numberPlayers; x++) {
    var number = `${x + 1}`
    var btn = document.createElement("button")
    btn.id = number
    btn.textContent = number

    btn.addEventListener("click", function(event){});

    document.body.appendChild(btn);
}

function display() {


    var screenElement = document.getElementById("screen");
    screenElement.value = players[x].question;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="screen" dir="ltr" READONLY /><br><br><br>
        <script src="script.js"></script><br>
        <input type="reset" id="clear" value="C" class="outB">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't call your `display()` function, and inside `display`, `x` isn't defined. I would start there.

Comment: Add Event Listeners:
You need to add event listeners to each button so that when a button is clicked, the corresponding question is displayed.

Scope of Variables:
The variable x is used in the display() function to access player questions. However, x should be passed as an argument to the display() function when the button is clicked. This way, each button click will pass the correct player index.